# USB device not being recognised as mass storage

Tags: usb, usb-drive, dmesg, lsblk

I recently bought an external SSD. My Windows laptop recognises the device just fine, but I can't mount it on my Linux machine.

The output of `lsusb | grep SanDisk` shows it there:

```
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 0781:558c SanDisk Corp. Extreme Portable SSD
```

However, the output of `lsblk` shows nothing but my `nvme0n1` drive:

```
NAME                    MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE  MOUNTPOINT
nvme0n1                 259:0    0 931.5G  0 disk  
├─nvme0n1p1             259:1    0   512M  0 part  /boot
└─nvme0n1p3             259:2    0 930.8G  0 part  
  └─cryptlvm            254:0    0 930.8G  0 crypt 
    ├─desk--vg-root 254:1    0  97.9G  0 lvm   /
    ├─desk--vg-home 254:2    0 816.9G  0 lvm   /home
    └─desk--vg-swap 254:3    0  15.9G  0 lvm   [SWAP]
```

`dmesg` shows that the USB device is detected, but it never sends the message "mass USB storage device detected". I've tried formatting using Windows to NTFS and exFAT (those are the only two options on explorer.exe, I'm trying others now), but still nothing shows

The `dmesg` logs:

```
[212261.611033] usb 2-4: new SuperSpeed Gen 1 USB device number 5 using xhci_hcd
[212261.637616] usb 2-4: New USB device found, idVendor=0781, idProduct=558c, bcdDevice=10.12
[212261.637619] usb 2-4: New USB device strings: Mfr=2, Product=3, SerialNumber=1
[212261.637620] usb 2-4: Product: Extreme SSD
[212261.637622] usb 2-4: Manufacturer: SanDisk
[212261.637623] usb 2-4: SerialNumber: 323034305435343030343537
[212316.230351] usb 2-4: USB disconnect, device number 5
[212329.695108] usb 2-4: new SuperSpeed Gen 1 USB device number 6 using xhci_hcd
[212329.720948] usb 2-4: New USB device found, idVendor=0781, idProduct=558c, bcdDevice=10.12
[212329.720951] usb 2-4: New USB device strings: Mfr=2, Product=3, SerialNumber=1
[212329.720953] usb 2-4: Product: Extreme SSD
[212329.720955] usb 2-4: Manufacturer: SanDisk
[212329.720956] usb 2-4: SerialNumber: 323034305435343030343537
```

Nothing is printed to the log after this `SerialNumber` line, which may be indicative of the problem

Comment: Try running this command `echo "0781:558c:u" | sudo tee /sys/module/usb_storage/parameters/quirks`

Answer (score 0):

After trying a bunch of different file system formats, I figured I should try rebooting my machine. Lo and behold, that worked!

I have absolutely no idea what was causing the problem. Sorry if this isn't useful for anyone experiencing the problem.

I eventually formatted to NTFS (since I need it for Linux / Windows usage) and that is picked up by both PCs